# Como importar o $scope atual para o $uibModal?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Tenho o seguinte modal no meu controller:

```
angular
.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('AlunosController', function ($uibModal, $scope, MyPaginator) {

     $scope.alunos = new MyPaginator('/alunos');

     $scope.open = function (aluno) {

       $scope.alunoOriginal = aluno;

       $uibModal.open({
           controller: 'ModalAlunoFormController',
           resolve: {
              aluno: function () {
                 return angular.copy(aluno);
              }
           }
       })
     };
})

.controller('ModalFormAlunoController', function ($uibModalInstance, aluno) {
    $scope.aluno = aluno;
});
```

Consigo importar perfeitamente o `aluno` para o `controller` da modal, o `ModalFormAlunoController`, usando a opção `resolve`.

Porém eu gostaria de passar todos os objetos presentes no `$scope` de `AlunosController` para o `ModalFormAlunoController`, sem ter que passar um por um via opção `resolve`.

Como posso fazer isso no *Angular UI Bootstrap*?

Answer (score 4):

Para fazer isso, você precisa passar a propriedade `scope` como opção de `$uibModal.open()`.

Basta apenas fazer isso:

```
$uibModal.open({
    controller: 'ModalController',
    scope: $scope,
});
```

Isso fará com que todos os objetos do `$scope` atual seja importado para o `$scope` do controller da modal.

Resposta no SOEN:

- [AngularJS passing data to bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286851/angularjs-passing-data-to-bootstrap-modal)

Tenho um exemplo no Codepen que está assim:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])

.controller("AppController", function($scope, $uibModal) {

    $scope.name = "Wallace";

    $scope.modalComScope = function(size) {

        $uibModal.open({
            scope: $scope,
            animation: false,
            // Esse vai exibir o nome do scope atual
            template: '<div class="modal-body">Meu nome é {{ name }}</div>',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            size: size,
        });
    };

   $scope.modalSemScope = function(size) {

        $uibModal.open({
            animation: false,
            // Esse não vai exibir o nome, pois o $scope não foi passado
            template: '<div class="modal-body">Meu nome é {{ name }}</div>',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            size: size,
        });
    };

})

.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance) {

    $scope.ok = function() {
        $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

Exemplo no [Codepen](http://codepen.io/wallacemaxters/pen/EgNBjX?editors=0010)

Answer (score -1):

Angular é 2 way data bind, ou seja, aquilo que você definir no $scope, está definido amigão, até que você faça algo para apagar o dado.

Em poucas palavras, basta você injetar $scope no controller da tua modal assim:

```
.controller('ModalFormAlunoController', function ($uibModalInstance, $scope) {
    console.log($scope.aluno);
})
```

Comment: Sim, mas isso aí vai passar só o `aluno`. Preciso  que todos os outros valores do `$scope` de `AlunosController` seja passado para `ModalFormAlunoController`. Ou seja, terei acesso a todas outras variáveis.

Comment: Quando faço o teste `console.log($scope.alunos)` no controller do Modal retorna `undefined`. O $scope principal não é passado automaticamente

Comment: Olá Wallace, retira "aluno" da injeção do controller, vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: vc esta tentando injetar um serviço "aluno" que não existe, e isso estava setando $scope.aluno para undefined.

Comment: Acho que você ainda não entendeu o que eu estava precisando. Eu preciso copiar os dados de um escopo para o outro.  Eu mesmo respondi na pergunta como fazer. Eu acho que é bom eu botar um exemplo para ninguém ficar confuso.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zachlysobey/d8edfdb73382314b6dd5

Comment: Não entendi como o código mostrado responde à pergunta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45708/discussion-between-wallace-maxters-and-newton-pasqualini-filho).